# Connection between: Expand a representation and dual representation

Tags: representation-theory, finite-groups

I worked the proof for 3) in [this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/186344/question-of-clifford-theory) out, but I have problems with the last step:

Let $\sigma$ be a irred. representation of a normal subgroup $H=\langle z\rangle$ of $G$ and $\sigma'$ its dual representation. The proof comes to the conclusion that
$$\sigma \text { is equivalent to } \sigma' \Leftrightarrow z^{-1}=z^{p^k}, $$
where $p$ is the charakteristic of the field $K$.

Where is the connection between saying that " $\sigma$ is equivalent to $\sigma'$ " and " $\sigma$ expands to a representation of $G$ "?

Comment: Please consider registering yourself with the site so that SE can help maintain your questions. Regards,

Comment: I'll do it when I'm back at home. Now i haven't my password with me.

Comment: I've changed $<z>$ to $\langle z\rangle$.  The code for the former is <z>; that for the latter is \langle z\rangle.