# Clifford theory and induction

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, representation-theory

in the answer to  [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/173811/faithful-irreducible-representations-of-cyclic-and-dihedral-groups-over-finite-f) there was the statement that a representation $\vartheta$ of a subgroup $\langle z\rangle$ can extend to a representation of the whole group $D_{2n}$.

If I start the other way round, this would mean that if the induced representation $\operatorname{Ind}(\vartheta)$ decomposes into two irreducibles $\vartheta_1$ and $\vartheta_2$,

1. $\vartheta_1$ and $\vartheta_2$ have the same degree (Why can't $\operatorname{Ind}(\vartheta)$ decompose into $2$ representation with different degrees?)
2. $\vartheta_1$ is the same representations as $\vartheta_2$. ( Why can't they be different?)

Comment: Thanks for the nice job formatting! Just a little FYI: you can obtain the brackets shown in the question statement by using `\langle z \rangle` to get $\langle z \rangle$.

Comment: Ok thanks, I will use it next time