# Group ring of a cyclic group over a finite field

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields

Suppose $ p $ a prime integer and $ n $ a positive integer. Does anyone know off the top of their heads if the group ring $ \mathbb{F}_{p}[\mathbb{Z}/n] $ (perhaps regarding $ \mathbb{Z}/n $ as the $ n^{\mathrm{th}} $ roots of unity is helpful) is isomorphic to $ \mathbb{F}_{p^n} $ in general?

Comment: This is not true. The splitting into summands depends on whether $p$ is a factor of $n$ and (more importantly) what is the smallest extension field of $\Bbb{F}_p$ that contains $n$th roots of unity (when $p$ and $n$ are coprime). Anyway, the block of the trivial representation will always be there, so the group ring cannot be a field.

Comment: See [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/153471/11619) for an explanation of what happens when $\gcd(n,p)=1$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For any field $F$ and a cyclic group G of order  $ n  $ the group ring is the  quotient of the polynomial ring in a varisble X by the ideal generated by $ X^ n-1$. As this polynomial is reducible this quotient ring will have zero divisors and hence cannot be field.